# Referencing of custom classes in Python

Tags: python, reference, immutability, mutable

I understand that custom classes in Python are generally mutable. So in the example below, any changes done to the argument `s` in the function `inc_age` is reflected back at the calling section.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
            self.name = name
            self.age = age

def inc_age(s):
    s.age += 1


s1 = Student("Test",5)
inc_age(s1)
print(s1.age) # 6
```

I tried to implement linked list in Python using custom class as shown below:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, data=0, next=None):
            self.data = data
            self.next = next

def next_node(L):
    L = L.next

end = ListNode(3)
mid = ListNode(2,end)
beg = ListNode(1,mid)

next_node(beg)
print(beg.data) # 1
```

My question is why the change in object `L` in the function `next_node` not observed at the calling section.

Comment: `L = L.next` changes the local variable `L`, which is then discarded because you never do anything with it. Did you mean to `return L`?

Comment: @kindall I know using a return will work. I was just curious how the change was reflected for `Student` object but not for `ListNode` object.

Comment: Are you coming to Python from some other language? Because if you're confused because you're trying to apply, say, C++ thinking to Python, that's easier to resolve than if you're confused because you're trying to apply some vague intuition that you can't really explain to Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short version is this:

- If you change attributes of the value in `L`, those will be represented in any other references to that value.
- If you just change the local variable `L` to be a name for a completely different value, that doesn't change anything but the local variable `L`.

If this seems confusing to you, you're not thinking correctly about what variables in Python are. In some languages, like C++, a variable is a location where a value lives. In other languages, like Python, a variable is just a name that you can look up in a namespace to find a value; the values live wherever they want.

So, `L =` doesn't do anything to whatever value `L` is a name for, it just makes `L` into a name, in the local namespace, for a different value.

But `L.next =` would make `next` into a name for a different value in the namespace of the value that `L` refers to. So any other name for the same value as `L` can see the change.

Answer (score 0):

You must address attributes using `self`, and avoid naming variables and attributes with the names of builtin methods (next):

- it is also better practice to build a linked list from the head
- In addition, I corrected a few typos

The output test enumerates all nodes from the head.

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, data=0, next_node=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = next_node

    def add_next_node(self, node):
        self.next_node = node


if __name__ == '__main__':
    beg = ListNode(1)
    mid = ListNode(2)
    end = ListNode(3)

    beg.add_next_node(mid)
    mid.add_next_node(end)

    current = beg
    while True:
        print(current.data)
        current = current.next_node
        if current is None:
            break
```

#### output:

```
1
2
3
```